# Were the dates of saints days moved as part of the Gregorian calendar reforms?

Tags: catholic-church, calendar

I understand that if one were to go back in time and ask a participant at the [battle of Agincourt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Agincourt) what the date was, he would (if he knew) say that it was the [16th of October](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/1fnhep/have_dates_and_calendars_been_adjusted_correctly/caff54k), he would also (more likely) say that it was — [famously](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/henryv/henryv.4.3.html) — [St Crispin's Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Crispin%27s_Day):

> This day is call’d the feast of Crispian.
>   He that outlives this day, and comes safe home,
>   Will stand a tip-toe when this day is nam’d,
>   And rouse him at the name of Crispian.

Currently, of course, we celebrate the anniversary of the event today, on the 25th of October — but we also call this day St Crispin's Day.

Did the dates of Saints Days move with the Gregorian calendar reforms? If so was this move done consistently, and at the time of the reforms or later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. All fixed festivals remained on the same date, for example Christmas was celebrated on 25 December Julian, and then on 25 December Gregorian. However, the Gregorian reform did affect Easter and the movable feasts dependent on Easter.

Comment: So when [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Crispin%27s_Day) St Crispin's Day falls on 25 October it is wrong; or was Shakespeare wrong, or at least anachronistic (as was writing after the reforms)?

Comment: Where did you find "16 October"?

Comment: 25 October 1415 in the Gregorian calendar is 16 October 1415 the Julian (as can be confirmed [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=battle+of+agincourt+date) or [here](http://www.stevemorse.org/jcal/julian.html)).

Comment: Before the reform St Crispin's day was celebrated on 25 October Julian. After the reform it was celebrated on 25 October Gregorian. Is that not clear?

Comment: That's clear, but if that's correct it doesn't explain how the battle could have taken place on St Crispin's Day, since in according to the calendar in use in 1415 the battle took place on 16 October.

Comment: No, it was on a date which the people of the time called "25 October". A modern historian can recalculate it as "16 October Gregorian" but that has no relevance for the people of the time.

Comment: Ah — so the battle (if you asked someone then) took place on ([despite with the Internet says](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/1fnhep/have_dates_and_calendars_been_adjusted_correctly/caff54k)) 25 October (St. Crispian's Day) and we are the ones celebrating the anniversary on the "wrong" day (technically): we should wait until 3 November?

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it. Maybe someone else would like to chime in.

Comment: By the way, "the internet says" lots of absurd things.

Comment: "I don't know how else to explain it" Why so frustrated? I think you've explained it — unless my statement above is wrong: it was 25 October (St Crispian's Day) *then*, in the calendar used at the time, which would have been 3 November in the calendar we use *now*.

Comment: Also note that (assuming you're correct) [Wolfram Alpha is wrong too](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=battle%20of%20agincourt%20date) — though that would be [no surprise](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97818/why-does-mathematicas-date-for-the-battle-agincourt-differ-from-the-us-navys), really.